# text in table header is not aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code for table header and the problem is that the header is not aligned.

```
<th>
<span class="control-label operation-l">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).Url) </span>
</th>
<th>
@Html.Label("User", new { @class = "control-label operation-l" })
</th>
```

The User text is little bit upper than the URL text,how should I move the 
Url text little bit up?

I try with style style `style="margin-top: 5px"` which is not working...
any idea?

Comment: "User text is little bit upper" - What is the user text in that code..? Please shared the generated `HTML` and css, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **style="line-height:30px"**
don't use margin-top: 5px